# Crash handler printing a backtrace

Tags: c++, exception, crash

I want to install a SIGSEGV and friends handler in C++ to print a stack trace and exit on a crash.

backtrace_symbols_fd from glibc is almost what I want, but it doesn't symbolize calls in anonymous namespaces. However, gdb deals with that just fine (I have symbols compiled in, DWARF etc).

What library would you recommend for my situation?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [`abi::__cxa_demangle`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html) - this should correctly demangle the output from `backtrace_symbols`.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the point. I can live with a mangled symbol name - but for anonymous namespace I get *no* symbol name! That's the problem.